# change ID of newly created object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically add html elements by using Jquery. Unfortunatelly, newly created elemets has the same id as previous elements, but I need different ids for them. How can i change the ID of newly created element? My JS which is adding the element looks like this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
    var regexp, time;
    time = new Date().getTime();
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
    var target = $(event.target);
    $('.booking-table').append($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
    return event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

If i check the html, the 'this' looks like this:

```
<a class="add_fields btn btn-primary booking-row add" data-id="70086373156920" data-fields="<tr> <td>
    <select id='100000';></tr> </td>"
   .....
```

How can i get the id='100000' value from 'this' element, so i can change it by using .prop?

I am new in JS so this is the solution i came with - get the ID after element is created and change it. Is it good attitude?

Thank you

Comment: `id` must be unique for newly created elements or already existing elements.

Comment: You do NOT need to need to `return` a `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Your question is not clear enough on what you are trying to do - whats the expected output.